# Sitecore 8.2 Farm Configuration Issues

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.2

I have configured mutil server Sitecore 8.2 Farm (For Development purpose)

My farm has 1 Cd, 1 Cm, 1 SQL and 1 Mongo DB(Collection) servers. There are couple of issues I am facing, after setup.

1. When I try to publish item, It gets stuck at initializing...But If I make      IISReset it works. But after few minutes again the same issue appears on publishing. I have checked the log files I get error "ERROR Unable to connect to server ServerIP:27017: Error: 18 - Authentication failed..". Even though the connection string is fine.
2. Secondly I don't see analytics database in mongoDB.

I am facing this issue in the initial sitecore site that is deployed after installation so there is no customization. Any help is much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

Port 27017 is the default MongoDB port. Probably the MongoDB connection string is the issue. Check the Authentication credentials are correct in the connection string.

Somethings like  this:

```
<add name="analytics" connectionString="mongodb://mongodb_user:password@localhost/analytics"/>
<add name="tracking.live" connectionString="mongodb://mongodb_user:password@localhost/tracking_live"/>
<add name="tracking.history" connectionString="mongodb://mongodb_user:password@localhost/tracking_history"/>
<add name="tracking.contact" connectionString="mongodb://mongodb_user:password@localhost/tracking_contact"/>
```

Also check your MongoDB version.
For Sitecore 8.2 you should use MongoDB 3.2 see:

[Mongo DB compatibility](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/platform/software_recommendations)

[Sitecore Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your publishing issue, have you validated your scalability settings have your instance name and publishing instance names correct?

If these values aren't correctly specified you can see the issue with it getting stuck. On the CM you need both InstanceName and PublishingInstanceName to be the same, and on CD you need the PublishingInstanceName set to the CM's InstanceName value.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if you can connect to MongoDB using same connection settings you are using with RoboMongo or MongoVue. You may have to open SSH endpoint from MongoDB server to allow remote SSH connections.